# Div still redirecting after resized window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that makes a div become a link when resizing window. Problem is that when I zoom back out the div is still redirecting.

The code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {         
    if ($(this).width() <= 1400) {

        $("#settings").click(function()  {
            window.location = "settings.php";
        });
    } else {
        $("#settings").click(function()  {
            $("#settingsDropdown").toggle();
        });
    }
}).triggerHandler('resize');
```

I tried adding `window.location = "#";` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both events are registered, you need to remove the first event handler for the click check the off event

you could do:

```
$(window).resize(function() {         
    if ($(this).width() <= 1400) {
        $("#settings").off( 'click' );  //  <------ Add this line 
        $("#settings").click(function()  {
            window.location = "settings.php";
        });
    } else {
        $("#settings").off( 'click' );  //  <------ Add this line 
        $("#settings").click(function()  {
            $("#settingsDropdown").toggle();
        });
    }
}).triggerHandler('resize');
```

Comment: better to simply change clcik handler and skip `resize` handler completely. `resize` triggers many times s econd during manual resize...clcik handler can be set once

Comment: @charlietfl, yes sure, but may be he has something else to do with the resize that he didn't share in his question, I guess we all skip parts that are not related to our problem in the question :)

Comment: that's irrelevant @AbuRomaïssae. No need for constant binding/unbinding. `resize` can certainly be used for other things...but most people don't realize how often it can fire

Answer (score 0):

You have to `unbind` event handlers which you don't want anymore
See [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Answer (score 0):

use bind and unbind

```
$(window).resize(function() {         
  $("#settings").unbind('click.redirectOrToggle');
  if ($(this).width() <= 1400) {
    $("#settings").bind('click.redirectOrToggle', function()  {
      window.location = "settings.php";
    });
  } else {
    $("#settings").bind('click.redirectOrToggle', function()  {
      $("#settingsDropdown").toggle();
    });
  }
}).triggerHandler('resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding different handlers, change the logic within the click handler itself and you can remove the `window.resize`

```
/* called outside of window resize*/
$('#settings').click(function(){
   if($(window).width() < 1400){
        window.location = "settings.php";
    }else{
      $("#settingsDropdown").toggle();
    }

})
```